# My power supply whines, is there anything I can do about it?

Tags: power-supply, noise

My computer is less than 6 months old and ever since I got it the power supply sometimes makes a whining noise. Even when the computer is off. It's a 600W ATX Corrsair. Is there anything I can do about it? I've got it plugged into a UPS.

Comment: Is it a fairly high pitch noise? Mine has a noise when shut off as well. I've got a CX500 Corrsair which does the same thing. I think it might be some capacitor that just makes that sound under "shut off" conditions. Get a powerstrip with an on/off button? That's what I did. Btw, my gfx also makes similar noises under high frequency loads when it runs.

Comment: Give it a cookie!  Or pick it up and comfort it, it might just be missing you.

Comment: If it's a high-pitch noise, then the PSU is probably under-loaded (i.e. a 600 Watt power supply is too much capacity for the low-power draw of the PC).  ATX PSUs tend to be tolerant of small loads, but there could be exceptions.  Try connecting a Kill-a-Watt meter to measure how much (or little) power that system really uses.

Comment: @DragonLord bizare that question is the same as mine (and I asked mine 2 years earlier) and it got 24 upvotes

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help...

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/282579-10-please-loud-noisy-power-supply

http://www.eetimes.com/design/power-management-design/4012244/Power-Tip-2-Taming-a-noisy-power-supply

Comment: Please give a little detail about what they say and why they're useful.

Comment: Neither link seems applicable. The first links seems to be about fan noise.  The second link is about electrical noise, not audible noise.